# array push doesn't work node.js

Tags: arrays, node.js

I have an array with user ID's and I'm trying to make an array with another identifier, I did this foreach and the push to the array doesn't work.

```
var playersTeamA = JSON.parse(li.team_a_players);
   var playersAfinal =  new Array();
   _.each(playersTeamA, function(item, index){
     connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id="'+parseInt(item)+'"', function(error, results, fields){
        var identify = results[0].identify;
        playersAfinal.push(identify);
      });
   });
```

playersTeamA is for example

> [1,2,3,4]

if I do

```
console.log(identify);
```

I see the correct result.

Thanks

Comment: @Roman, yes, I tested with results[0].identify and with identify

Comment: and it was your aspected result? ok, than your query isn't wrong..

Comment: The query is correct, im 100% sure

Comment: why you hit sql query in loop ? Use SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN (1,2,3); It will give you result set at once. This is not related to your question. It just a suggestion

Comment: Someone I still didnt find a solution?